# Incompatible Generics Issue in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am attempting to create a class hierarchy related to the **Binary Tree** data structure. Note that none of what I am using involves anything from **java.util**. In doing so, I have gone out of my way to make everything as OO as possible by using inheritance, generics, etc. Right now I have 2 interfaces, 2 classes, and 1 inner class, respectively:

```
 public interface BinaryTreeADT<E>
 public interface BinarySearchTreeADT<E> extends BinaryTreeADT<E>
 public class BinaryTree<E extends Comparable<E>> implements BinaryTreeADT<E>
 public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> extends BinaryTree<E> implements BinarySearchTreeADT<E>
 protected static class BTNode<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

Here are both interfaces:

```
    public interface BinaryTreeADT<E extends Comparable<E>>
{
    void insert(E e); // insert element into tree
    //E remove(E e); // delete and return element from tree
    E find(E e); // find element in tree
    void preorder(); // preorder traversal (DFS)
    void postorder(); // postorder traversal (DFS)
    void inorder(); // inorder traversal (DFS)
    void levelorder(); // levelorder (BFS) traversal
}
    public interface BinarySearchTreeADT<E extends Comparable<E>> extends BinaryTreeADT<E>
{
    E findMin(); // Finds min elemeht in tree
    E findMax(); // Finds max element in tree
    E delete(E e); // Delete an element from the tree
    //E kthSmallest(); // Find kth smallest element in tree
}
```

**UPDATE: Here is the full compiler error message:**
https://titanpad.com/J9FG90FvRi

How do I properly sync these generic types? Also, has there been a concept missed and am not fully understanding?

Comment: Where do you get these errors?  Nothing here looks obviously wrong.

Comment: One issue is that the find(E#1) in BinarySearchTree cannot implement find(E#2) in BinaryTreeADT.

Comment: Can we see a bit more code?  This still isn't enough information to see anything wrong.

Comment: Try adding `extends Comparable<E>` to the interfaces too.

Comment: @Andreas when I add `extends Comparable<E>` I get the second error message shown above. I'll add more code.

Comment: As comment above from Andreas says you have to add <E extends Comparable <E>> to interfaces so do public interface BinaryTreeADT<E extends Comparable <E>> and when implementing interface you do public class BinaryTree<E1 extends E> implements BinaryTreeADT<E>

Comment: @MichaelDD when I do that i get  `cannot find symbol
public class BinaryTree<E1 extends E> implements BinaryTreeADT<E> symbol: class E`

Comment: If it's possible provide code for interfaces so we can help otherwise it's just people guessing what's the problem

Comment: @MichaelDD I added both interfaces

Comment: I don't see any problem with interfaces however I might be wrong so I would wait for answers from more experienced users however posting whole error stack tree from compiler would be better so if you can copy and paste here whole error you are getting from compiler

Comment: @MichaelDD I added the entire error stack tree in a link in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `E extends Comparable<? super E>`. This will allow classes as E, that implement Comparable for a supertype (for example classes that implement `Comparable<Object>`).

I'm not sure whether this solves *all* of your problems. But maybe some of them.

Comment: I updated my code to include this. Can you check out the stack error tree:  https://titanpad.com/J9FG90FvRi